# How to skip first value of an observable with RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular project I use this component what is replresent an input field in a form. The goal is to save the value of the input field on-the-fly if user changed it:

```js
export class SettingInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() model: SettingInterface;

  private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

  private appDataService: AppDataServiceInterface<SettingInterface> =
    new AppDataFactoryService<SettingInterface>().get(Setting);

  private value$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.model.value);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(this.saveSetting().subscribe());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }

  emitToSave(): void {
    this.value$.next(this.model.value);
  }

  private saveSetting(): Observable<any> {
    return this.value$.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),

      distinctUntilChanged(),

      switchMap(() => this.appDataService.save(this.model)
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<third-party-input
  type="text"
  [value]="model.value"
  (change)="emitToSave()"
></third-party-input>
```

The problem is when the component initializing the `saveSetting()` observable will fire. I want to avoid this behavior and fire only when user change the model's value property.

How can I avoid the firing on initialization and fireing only when user change the value?

Comment: what will be the initial value of `this.model.value` ?

Comment: it can be anything... a string, a number or boolean, depends on the model type. But I think this isn't important. The `this.model.value` has an initial data in every case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I think skip method would help here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/skip)

**Example**

```js
const { of, iif, pipe , BehaviorSubject, Subscription, operators: { distinctUntilChanged, skip, switchMap, debounceTime } } = rxjs;

const value$ = new BehaviorSubject("initial");
const model = {}

const appDataService = {
    save(model) {      
      return of(model);
    }
}

const saveSetting = () => value$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((model) => appDataService.save(model))
    );

saveSetting().subscribe(console.log);

setInterval(() => {
value$.next(Math.random().toString());
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: sounds good, but this is still firing when I click the field and press any key what does not changes the value... for example arrow keys. It fires on first arrow key press.

Comment: In that case you would need `filter` method, when you press `arrow key` what value is getting through observable? [Is it similar to KeyboardEvent.key?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). You can inspect that with quick `tap(console.log)` expression placed inside pipe method.

Comment: One guess, `pipe(skip(1), filter(pr => !['ArrowUp', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowDown'].includes(pr)), ...)`

Comment: the `distinctUntilChanged()` say something like this...

Answer (score 0):

I think u can maintain a boolean flag along with `filter` operator initially it will `true` and with the change it will become `false`.

```
private isFirstTime = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscriptions.add(this.saveSetting().subscribe());
}
 
emitToSave(): void {
 this.isFirstTime = false;
 this.value$.next(this.model.value);
} 

private saveSetting(): Observable<any> {
 return this.value$.pipe(
   filter(_ => !isFirstTime)
   debounceTime(500),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   switchMap(() => this.appDataService.save(this.model)
 );
}
```

Comment: sounds good, but this is still firing when I click the field and press any key what does not changes the value... for example arrow keys. But now it fires after the second key press.